# Make button in absolute centered and middle of page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a single page with a large button that is always in the absolute middle/center of the page. I want the button-text to be large, but when I make it large it offsets the button and it is no longer in the middle. What am I doing wrong here?

(I also have bootstrap installed and am glad to use rows/columns/offsets too)

**CSS**

```
.btn-text {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: 'Corben';
    font-size: 580%;
}

.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    padding: 20%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
...
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="btn btn-large btn-primary" id="oujh-button">
      <div class="btn-text">BUTTON</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
...
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/50ye58oe/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using CSS3 transforms is OK(if you don't need to support IE<9) you could do this:

```
.btn{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Rad, that totally worked. I definitely am not supporting IE<9

Comment: I'm glad! This is a really practical approach for centering anything inside it's (relative) container. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the Bootstrap `center-block` class to horizontally center the button and a flexbox to vertically center it.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="center-block btn btn-large btn-primary" id="oujh-button">
      <div class="btn-text">BUTTON</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-text {
    font-family: 'Corben';
    font-size: 280%;
}

.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```